# Angular-Ui-Router state changes but template URL doesn't load for nested states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on an a requirejs + angularjs project with ui-router . I tried to implement nested views but only the state changes but the template URL doesn't load.

My route-config.js

```
.state(ROUTE.auditGroup, {
  abstract: true,
  authenticate: true,
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'AuditMain'
  },
  views: {
    'user': {
      templateUrl: GLOBAL.viewPath + '/auditgroup.html',
    }
  }
})

.state(ROUTE.audit, {
  url: '/audit',
  authenticate: true,
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'Audit'
  },
  views: {
    'nested': {
      templateUrl: GLOBAL.viewPath + '/audit.html',
      controller: 'auditCtrl',
    }
  },
  ncyBreadcrumb: {
    label: 'Audit',
  }
})

.state(ROUTE.allidentifiers, {
  url: '/allidentifiers',
  authenticate: true,
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'All Identifiers'
  },
  views: {
    'nested': {
      templateUrl: GLOBAL.viewPath + '/audit.allidentifiers.html',
      controller: 'allidentifiersCtrl',
    }
  },
  ncyBreadcrumb: {
    label: 'All Identifiers',
  }
})
```

My auditgroup.html

```
<div ui-view="nested"></div>
```

The Audit Page Works fine but, the allidentifiers page is not injected.
Everything works fine except nested views, I could not figure out the exact problem , state changes successfully but the template URL doesn't load.
Need assistance.

Plunkr https://embed.plnkr.co/oRMnMW4QoWwhSkm9maHf/

Goto > list>Second Nested

I want to include second nested template in same view

Comment: Put up a fiddle

Comment: here is the plunk I made https://plnkr.co/edit/qW5JoXL7nffbbaS1CreZ?p=preview. Goto List and Click second nested button I want the new content insted of the existing list

Comment: @SamarRizvi.I have attached the plunkr

Comment: Please see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `ui-view` for the nested template to show. See the updated plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/oRMnMW4QoWwhSkm9maHf?p=preview